# Things to consider for a team-based programming interview

Tags: interviewing, team-role

In the next day I am going to be interviewed for a software engineering position, and the interview is going to be a team-based programming exercise.Interviewees are going to be paired , and submitted a programming exercise to be solved using a laptop. The partner is not known in advance and can be anybody. Well, that's a first for me.

How to prepare oneself for cooperation?
How to put all the odds in my favor (or of my team)?

Comment: Here is a related question - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11475/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-a-group-exercise-for-potential-new-hires-to-see-how-the

Comment: You are being teamed up with someone that is also competing with you for the same position? That should be interesting...

Comment: It seems to me that you should prepare yourself the same way as you would for any other interview, and then do your best and work with your patner as if they were your work colleague. I'm not sure what else one can expect, or what sort of an answer we are fishing for here?