# What is the next step on the growth path of a first line manager, and how to reach it?

Tags: management, career-development

Sorry if anything like this has been asked before but it perfectly represents my internal situation:

I am afraid that my team, whom I managed and developed from scratch, don't need me anymore. They are truly self-sufficient and I have spent a lot of time focusing on developing my management skills. Meanwhile, I have worked less and less hands-on.

I think I am on a good path of becoming a manager, but the way the business is growing, there might just be nothing to manage anymore.. except if I get to the next step.

So, what is the next step and how do I get there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I did a good job delegating all my work to a team I built, and there is no work left, am I redundant?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24625/if-i-did-a-good-job-delegating-all-my-work-to-a-team-i-built-and-there-is-no-wo)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, congratulations!  If you have developed a self sufficient team, then you have done your job.

For your next step, look around your organization.  Is there some need that is not being met that interests you?  If so, you've just found your next project (I do recommend getting some management buy-in if it proceeds significantly).

Second, bring up your concerns with your boss.  If he or she is truly supportive, then you won't be viewed as excess weight, but rather someone who can lead a team to self sufficiency.  Ask about other projects and ask to be assigned to those.  I suspect you will get more "points" if you have already researched existing projects and some in mind when you approach your boss, but don't be disappointed if you are assigned to something else.