# Should I tell my current employer about a new job offer before I accept it

Tags: ethics, resignation, united-kingdom

I am a software developer at a large corporation in the UK which I have worked for for 3 and a half years. For the last year I have been working on a fairly large and important project which is just about coming to a close. I would say I was pivotal to the completion of this project and want to see it through to the end.

I've been unhappy with my job for a while and have raised my issues with management several times. Chief complaints have been lack of pay rises, lack of training, and not being able to advance my career. I recently worked out that taking inflation into account, I earn less today than I did when I started.

I have been interviewing recently and just received an offer. It's a little bit lower than I was asking (by £500) but I'm still probably going to accept it. I have another two interviews next week which I want to attend to see what kind of offers they might have.

However, given my current position on this project, and I'm getting asked what my availability is for future work, I feel like I should give my manager a heads-up that I will be leaving, even though I haven't formally accepted an offer yet. Should I?

Comment: The answer is simply **no, of course not. Say nothing**. But this is a multi-multi-duplicate.

Comment: Telling your current employer about another job *offer* is playing a game, where people have to decide what their time and money are worth, and ends with one of these employers retaining you. But not before you accept at the new employer. You always need to be prepared to follow through on these plays. But, you don't appear to be playing that game. Accept somewhere before you say anything to anyone.

Comment: see also: [How can I prepare for getting hit by a bus?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9128/168)

Comment: I did try searching for this but I didn't think any of the other questions I found adequately answered this specific scenario. But thank you @gnat, that other question and the answers here have provided some useful advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered on numerous occasions and **the quick answer is No**.

Regardless of your position at your current employer, things can turn sour surprisingly rapidly. The downside by telling them is that you immediately might find yourself without a job. The potential upside is only a warm a fuzzy and feeling of you being a good person.

You have raised your concerns and they have been ignored. You are under no moral obligation to give them a 'heads up' that you might be leaving.

My guess is that your employer will not be terribly surprised that you have looked elsewhere.

Comment: Very unlikely to immediately find themselves without a job in the UK.  Even if the OP was fired on the spot (which would be illegal), the employer would still have to pay them for their contractual notice (which is probably either one month or three months).

Answer (score 0):

Your notice period is there to sort out whatever handover is necessary. Good on you for wanting to see the project through to the end, but remember that it's **not your problem** - to use the classic language, if you were hit by a bus tomorrow, what would your employer do?

If you really want to help your old employer out, you could offer to your new employer to delay your start date to allow you to finish your current project. But remember your old employer doesn't give you pay rises, training or career advancement - it doesn't sound like they're looking after you.