# How to keep a good relationship with ex-colleagues who will have to finish work on many on-going projects?

Tags: work-environment, new-job, ex-colleagues

I started a job 7 months ago and got involved on about 15 different project teams. 10 are unfinished, ongoing projects. Additionally, due in part to my prior experience, the company had a very good resume and won some very lucrative upcoming project work from Clients that knew me well. Now I will be taking a new job. My current colleagues, will have to finish ongoing projects and have an increased workload, especially with the upcoming new work. They do not have my skill-set, so will likely struggle somewhat until they come up to speed. Many of them already work 50+ hours a week keeping up with their own assignments. How can I maintain a good relationship with them while they take on the extra and challenging work due to my departure? I could see them being very upset and one or more Clients being unhappy about losing me on their projects, which may create additional tensions.

I understand that having a good handoff is helpful, however there will be no time for that. So my focus is on good relationships being maintained in spite of the company policy not to determine who will fill the departing person's roles until after they leave. Never has my department wanted to have work transitioned before the departure. They want to squeeze every last drop out of us on project work. Transition meetings are a waste of time in the Director's view. They will 'figure it out', and leadership usually Stokes the flames by bad-mouthing departed employees, in an attempt to say they were never needed. Any tips to counteract this? Or are hand-off meetings the only way? (These would have to happen on our own time, as management has never, and likely will never be a proponent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prepare for getting hit by a bus?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/how-can-i-prepare-for-getting-hit-by-a-bus)

Comment: In that question the person theoretically dies. No death implied here. I will be accessible to my old workmates and am interested in good relationships.

Comment: if you click the link "hit by a bus" over there you'll find that it's just a popular idiom that is not intended to do anything with sudden deaths: "The bus factor is a measurement of the risk resulting from information and capabilities not being shared among team members..."

Comment: That post seems to address problems with the work after leaving, not interpersonal relationships - my concern. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as thorough a hand over as you can and work to set them up as well as possible prior to your departure. That's about all there is to it really.

Most will probably realise that you aren't doing this to them; you aren't deliberately making their lives harder. People move on - it's the nature of jobs. If anyone takes it personally, well there's probably not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

If your colleagues are sensible people they will see the problem created by you leaving is an issue with your employer and not with you. Therefore you won't need to worry about keeping a good relationship with them.

Assuming you're not overestimating yourself/underestimating them. It sounds like your company has created a situation where you have a very high 'bus factor'. This is down to poor management on their behalf not down to you.

If any of your colleagues are hurt you've left it is really more their problem. Don't apologise for progressing your own career.